# Retrieving object form Many 2 Many Relationship in Gorm (posgtgres)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have two models

```
type Role struct {
    models.BaseModel
    UID         uuid.UUID    `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();uniqueIndex:idx_uniqueGroupId" form:"id" xml:"id" json:"id"`
    Name        string       `gorm:"size:150;uniqueIndex:idx_uniqueGroup" form:"name" xml:"name" json:"name"`
    Permission []Permission `gorm:"many2many:roles_permissions;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;" form:"rolePermissions" xml:"rolePermissions" json:"rolePermissions"`
}
```

and

```
type Permission struct {
    models.BaseModel
    UID   uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();uniqueIndex:idx_uniquePermId" form:"id" xml:"id" json:"id"`
    Model string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_uniquePerm" form:"entity" xml:"entity" json:"entity"`
    Name  string    `gromr:"uniqueIndex:idx_uniquePerm" form:"name" xml:"name" json:"name"`
}
```

I created a function which will return role with related permissions as

```
func GetRoleByUid(uid uuid.UUID, db *gorm.DB) (*Role, error) {
    var role Role
    if err := db.Model(&Role{}).Preload("Permissions").Find(&role, "uid = ?", uid).Error ; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if role.UID == uuid.Nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Role not Found")
    }
    return &role, nil
}
```

But i got an error  `"Permissions: unsupported relations for schema Role"`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: change `Permission []Permission` to `Permissions []Permission` in struct `Role`

Comment: There is a typo in the Permission type: `gromr: